# How to remove application path by using httpd config in weblogic plugin

Tags: ajax, apache, plugins, weblogic12c

I developed a JSF application that named myapp was deployed on weblogic 12c http server on managed servers managedServer1 and managedServer2 in same cluster that named *mycluster* . Application can be access by url http://xx.xx.xx.xx(ip for managedServer1):9080/myapp.

I tried add a apache load balancer http server in the front of weblogic cluster by configure httpd (httpd.conf) as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.mywebsite.com.au
ServerAlias mywebsite.com.au

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
  BalancerMember http://xx.xx.xx.xx1:9080/myapp
  BalancerMember http://xx.xx.xx.xx2:9080/myapp
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
  Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /myapp balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse /myapp balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/

<Location />
  Require all granted
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

by using this configure, I can access my jsf app by URL

```
http://www.mywebsite.com.au
```

directly.

Unfortunately, As my JSF App have quite lots ajax asynch requests in my jsf pages, apache reverse proxy not handle it properly, always cause session lost. I have to find alternative way to fulfil my ajax requests.

I fellow Oracle advice to install weblogic plug in for my apache http server. After installed plug in, I re-configuring my httpd.conf by using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mywebsite.com.au
<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
  WebLogicCluster xx.xx.xx.xx1:9080,xx.xx.xx.xx2:9080
  MatchExpression *.xhtml
</IfModule>
<Location /myapp>
  SetHandler weblogic-handler
  Require all granted
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately. I have to access my JSF application by call URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com.au/myapp
```

My question is: Does there is an other way to configure my virtual host to be accessed my JSF app from root? (http://www.mywebsite.com.au) that with out application path. If it is, please advise!

Comment: It is simple enough to have both `http://www.mywebsite.com.au/myapp` and `http://www.mywebsite.com.au/` send traffic to Weblogic via a rewrite rule in Apache. On your subsequent clicks, do you still expect the `context path` to be hidden or can it be shown then? Also, do you serve your static content from Weblogic (like images/css/js) or is this from Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days work, find a way to solve this issue, httpd.conf was update to:

```
<Location />
  SetHandler weblogic-handler
  PathTrim /myapp
  PathPrepend /myapp
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

By using PathTrim and PathPrepend to map URL. System works well now.

This issue maybe help any one else who is in the same situation.